# MultipartEntity post array

Tags: android, file, http, multipartentity

I'm trying to upload file using http post request. I figured this is doable using MultipartEntity, as such:

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
...
entity.addPart("caption", new StringBody("myCaption"));
entity.addPart("file", new FileBody(file));
entity.addPart("uploadername", new StringBody("myName"));
...
```

My problem now is the structure by which the post request needs to be made.
Instead of the rather straightforward...

```
{
    "caption":[caption],
    "file":[file to upload],
    "uploadername":[name]
}
```

..it is..

```
{
    "newfile":
    {
        "caption":[caption],
        "file":[file to upload]
    },
    "uploadername":[name]
}
```

If I don't need to post files, I can use JSONObject and put one JSONObject inside the other, but I can't figure out a way to do so for MultipartEntity.
Any clues? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

..Okay, guess I found a way to do it.

```
....
entity.addPart("newfile[caption]", new StringBody("myCaption"));
entity.addPart("newfile[file]", new FileBody(file));
entity.addPart("uploadername", new StringBody("myName"));
...
```